# Mean.js & MongoDB non-blocking development, when to save object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is my first time posting here (meaning the first time I don't find the answer to my question...)

Being quite new to node.js development, I am trying very hard to keep in mind the non-blocking development. Here is what I am trying to do:

This is my Mongoose schema:

```
var OfferSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, trim: true },
  ...
  pictures:[{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Media'}],
  ...
});
```

Then, I have my create function which will create an offer. To do that, I'm calling a webpage using jsdom:

```
var createOffer = function(){
        var offer = new Offer();
        offer.pictures = [];
        //Doing stuff

        var media = ['https://media1.location','https://media2.location',...];
        media.forEach(function(elt){
          //Here I'm calling for webpages and waiting for the answer
          request(elt,function(error,response,body){
             offer.pictures.push(body);
             //Should I save here?
             offer.save();
          });
        });

};
```

(not-tested sample code, for illustration purposes)

So basically, I am waiting for external webpages in order to complete my object. And here is my question: when should I use the offer.save() ?  what is the best practice?

=> should I save() each time my callback gets called?

=> should I think of a "countig callback answers" mechanism which increments each time a callback gets called, and save only when all callbacks are called?

=> is this choice (save every time or save once) is linked to the number of elements?

Many thanks for your help!

***Edit:*** going deeper into this code, I have tested both options and I really don't understand the behaviour:

So here is my code:

```
if(window.images){
    var nbPics = 0;
    var nbPicsProcessed = 0;
    window.images.forEach(function(imageUrl){
        nbPics++;
        if(imageUrl.substring(0,2) === '//'){
            imageUrl = imageUrl.replace('//','https://');
        }
        //Will give me a Mongoose Media object
        mediaController.getOrCreateMediaByUrl(imageUrl,function(err,media,created){
            nbPicsProcessed++;
            console.log('Pictures, nbPics='+nbPics+', nbPicsProcessed='+nbPicsProcessed);
            //I'm adding my media to my "Offer" object (in an Array)
            offer.pictures.push(media);

            //If I remove this condition, my code has unexpected behaviour
            if(nbPicsProcessed === nbPics){
                offer.save();
                console.log('Pictures, saving... Array size: '+offer.pictures.length);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Alright, so here is my execution result:

```
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=1
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=2
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=3
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=4
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=5
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=6
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=7
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=8
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=9
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=10
Pictures, saving... Array size: 10
```

And if I look at my "offer" object in MongoDb, I found the 10 elements, everything works perfectly...
Now, I'm doing exactly the same, but removing the if(nbPicsProcessed === nbPics) conditions => so I would save the object every time instead of just once:

```
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=1
Pictures, saving... Array size: 1
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=2
Pictures, saving... Array size: 2
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=3
Pictures, saving... Array size: 3
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=4
Pictures, saving... Array size: 4
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=5
Pictures, saving... Array size: 5
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=6
Pictures, saving... Array size: 6
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=7
Pictures, saving... Array size: 7
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=8
Pictures, saving... Array size: 8
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=9
Pictures, saving... Array size: 9
Pictures, nbPics=10, nbPicsProcessed=10
Pictures, saving... Array size: 10
```

So, much more save() called, but I would expect it to have the same result... but if i look into the created object, I have 75 objects into my Array!!!

Does anyone has a reasonnable explanation?

Comment: What does your code for your method `offer.save()` appear as?

Comment: 10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 55.  `media` is an array and doing `offer.pictures.push(media)` adds not just one object, but a whole array of objects to `offer.pictures` ... meaning that your second example without the `if (nbPicsProcessed === nbPics)` actually saves one, then saves two additional, then saves 3 additional to the two and the one... and so on

Comment: hi! the offer.save() method is the standard mongoose save. So it should save this object into mongoDB. And, sova, I thought about this maths, and tried to explain why I was getting 75 objects and not 55. So I looked up what exactly was saved in my array in mongo DB, turns out the 5 first pictures appears 10 times, and the last 5 pictures appears 5 times...

Comment: So for each image in the `window` variable you're invoking `mediaController.getOrCreateMediaByUrl()` ...  what exactly does this method refer to?  I ask because you pass a function(){} as an argument, and if this method has any callbacks it may be invoking things more than once.